# CodeIgniter, muestra los primeros 10 elementos los restantes no salen, se muestra lo ultimo, usando modal

Tags: codeigniter, modal

tengo una lista modal y solo me muestra bien los 10 primeros, cuando paso a la siguiente ventana me muestra cualquiera cosa de lo ultimos que toque pero no saca el valor real que puede ser. mi lista tiene 25 elementos

vista lista.php

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-view-asistencias" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default" value="<?php echo $modulod->id;?>">
<span class="fa fa-search"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

Vista footer.php

```
$(".btn-view-asistencias").on("click", function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "registro/asistencias/view",
            type:"POST",
            data:{idasistencias:id},
            success:function(resp){
                $("#modal-default .modal-body").html(resp);
            }

        });
    });
```

cual puede ser el error

Comment: Por favor muestra lo que tienes en tu controlador y tu modelo para entender la causa de tu problema

Comment: class Competencias_model extends CI_Model {

 public function getCompetencias(){
  $this->db->select("l.*");
  $this->db->from("lista l");  
  $this->db->where("l.estado","1");
  $resultados = $this->db->get();
  return $resultados->result();
 }

Comment: class Competencias extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model("Competencias_model");
 }

 public function index()
 {
  $data  = array(
   'registro' => $this->Competencias_model->getRegistroParticipanteTot(),
   'competencias' => $this->Competencias_model->getCompetencias()   
  );
      
  $this->load->view("layouts/header");
  $this->load->view("layouts/aside");
  $this->load->view("admin/competencias/list",$data);
  $this->load->view("layouts/footer");

 }

Comment: Ok hay que aprender a usar mejor stackoverflow, edita tu post/pregunta de esta pagina y pon ahi tu codigo, porque ponerlo aqui sale todo sin formato y asi no dan ganas de ayudarte